# Rails Helper Syntax Errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to pull in a field to my homepage view, which has a significant JS component (it is an apartment bookings calendar).

In the index.html.erb file, there is a js variable called 'sections', which defines what displays on a given column in the calendar being displayed. I have been testing it with static values, but what I need to do is display the apartment names, which are held in a db field.

I am using a helper to try to achieve this, but I am getting two errors:

syntax error, unexpected keyword_do, expecting keyword_end <% clients.each do |a| %>

and

syntax error, unexpected tSTRING_DEND, expecting keyword_end

I'd like to understand better what is causing these errors, and how to correct the code as below:

```
module HomeHelper
     def sections(client)
      <% clients.each do |a| %>
    {key: <%= a.id, label: <%= a.appartmentaddress %>}
    <% end %>
    end 
    end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails helpers are ruby scripts. You don't need to use `erb` syntax inside them.

To be honest I do not really get what you are trying to do and if a helper is the best place to do this but just try to remove the `<% %>` from your code and check if you 'll get rid of the syntax errors.

Comment: Thanks, that removes the errors :-)
Maybe I didn't explain the use case so well.

In the index.html.erb file, there is a js variable called 'sections', which defines what displays on a given column in the calendar being displayed. I have been testing it with static values, but what I need to do is display the apartment names, which are held in a db field.

Comment: Will do -I have a new error now:

'undefined local variable or method 'apartments' on this code:

`module HomeHelper

    def sections(apartment)
     apartments.each do |a| 
    {key: a.id, label: a.appartmentaddress }
      end 
     end 
    end`

Do you see a problem there or should I post a brand new question?

Comment: You are passing `apartment ` in the def but you are iterating `apartments` inside the method. So you have to switch one of them!